# UDP Client works but doesn't receive response from client

Tags: sockets, udp

I have this code for a UDP client and it works without errors, but either doesnt receive an output or doesnt print it.

```
import socket

target_host = '127.0.0.1'
target_port = 80

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

client.sendto(b"GET /HTTP/ 1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n", (target_host, target_port))

data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)

print(data)
```

Comment: UDP is an unreliable protocol. One does not get any errors if sending fails. It is not even clear what is at the server side, i.e. if there is something at all. So this code by its own is not sufficient to reproduce your problem but you need to show the server side too.

Comment: HTTP uses TCP, not UDP. Also, your HTTP request is malformed anyway, the 2nd space character is in the wrong position